# How do I made it so that the sides of this ribbon banner isn't transparent?

Tags: html, css, ribbon, banner

I was wondering how to make the bottom ribbon show the left and right side of the ribbon? The top one shows perfectly fine but when I add a background color to the page, the left and right side of the ribbon disappear.

I've been stuck on this for awhile so I was wondering what the solution is to fix this? Thank you in advance!

```css
body {
  text-align: center;

}

section {
  background-color: aqua;
}

h6 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 34px;
  line-height: 28px;
  color: #8699a0;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #758890;
  margin: 120px 0;
  font-family: arial, verdana;
  outline: none;
  padding: 14px 30px;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  box-shadow:
    0 0 30px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1),
    0 36px 0 -18px #b1e3e2;
}

/*the ribbon ends*/
h6:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 18px;
  left: -15%;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 130%;
  /*Using the triangle logic - 2-sided borders and 0 height. That will create negative triangles on the left and right.*/
  height: 0;
  border: 28px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-left: 28px solid #b1e3e2;
  border-right: 28px solid #b1e3e2;
}

h6:after {
  content:"";
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  border-top: 18px solid #99acb2;
  border-left: 18px solid transparent;
  border-right: 18px solid transparent;
}

h6, h6:before {
  background-image:
    /*2 gray borders*/
    linear-gradient(
      transparent 8%,
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 8%,
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 14%,
      transparent 14%,
      transparent 86%,
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 86%,
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 92%,
      transparent 92%
    ),
    /*white gloss gradient*/
    linear-gradient(
      rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75),
      rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)
    ),
    /*thin stripes*/
    linear-gradient(
      45deg,
      transparent 40%,
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 40%,
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 60%,
      transparent 60%
      ),
    /*white base*/
    linear-gradient(white, white);
  background-size:
    cover, /*borders*/
    cover, /*white gloss*/
    4px 4px, /*thin stripes*/
    cover; /*base white*/
}

h6, h6:before, h6:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /*fix to make the borders appear on the ribbon ends as well*/
  background-origin: border-box;
}
```

```html
<h6>BUY ONLINE AND SAVE</h6>

<section>
  
<h6>BUY ONLINE AND SAVE</h6>
  
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are setting your h6:before and h6:after element one level to the background with z-index-1 to put them behind your h6.

if you add a position relative and a z-index of whatever value to your section, it will all come to the front.

```
section {
  background-color: aqua;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0; // works with any value
}
```

The important point to your solution, is that by adding position and z-index to your section, you define it as your stacking context root element, instead of HTML root, moving automatically any child, even with negative z-index in front of it.
In short, this is the stacking order:

1. The stacking context’s root element
2. Positioned elements (and their
   children) with negative z-index values (higher values are stacked in
   front of lower values; elements with the same value are stacked
   according to appearance in the HTML)
3. Non-positioned elements (ordered by appearance in the HTML)
4. Positioned elements (and their children) with a z-index value of auto(ordered by appearance in the
   HTML)
5. Positioned elements (and their children) with positive z-index
   values (higher values are stacked in front of lower values; elements
   with the same value are stacked according to appearance in the HTML)

See the following article for a more complete explanation of stacking
https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Answer (score 0):

The trick it to avoid applying any effect on the main element and keep everything on pseudo elements then you will be able to simply add `z-index:0` to main element to avoid the issue by making everything belong to the same stacking context.

Here is the modified code:

```css
body {
  text-align: center;

}

section {
  background-color: aqua;
}

h6 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 34px;
  color: #8699a0;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #758890;
  margin: 120px 0;
  outline: none;
  padding: 14px 30px;
  position: relative;
  z-index:0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  box-shadow:
    0 0 30px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1),
    0 36px 0 -18px #b1e3e2;
}

h6:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -2;
  top: 18px;
  bottom: -18px;
  left: -40px;
  right:-40px;
  background:
  linear-gradient(to top left,transparent 49.8%,#99acb2 50%) right 40px top 100%/20px 18px no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(to top right,transparent 49.8%,#99acb2 50%) 40px 100%/20px 18px no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(#b1e3e2,#b1e3e2) center/calc(100% - 120px) 100% no-repeat,
  
    linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)) 0 8%/100% 6% no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)) 0 92%/100% 6% no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75),rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)) no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 40%,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 40%,
            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 60%,transparent 60%) left/4px 4px,
    #fff;
}

h6:after {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  right:0;
  left: 0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  z-index: -1;
  background:
    linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)) 0 8%/100% 6% no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)) 0 92%/100% 6% no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75),rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)) no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 40%,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 40%,
            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 60%,transparent 60%) left/4px 4px,
    #fff;
}

h6, h6:before, h6:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<h6>BUY ONLINE AND SAVE</h6>

<section>
  
<h6>BUY ONLINE AND SAVE</h6>
  
</section>
```